# MySQL pdo select single column with limit but return one row

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get the last 3 records from my table + only the titles column but I get only one result.

```
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM tutorials LIMIT 3");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $key => $value) { echo $value; }
```

Is working if I use fetchAll but in my case I don't need all the columns, just the only one(title) so there is no sense using fetchall but why is returning only one row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fetch` retrieves *one* row, or it returns FALSE if there is no row to fetch. (We could do the processing in a loop, and `fetch` each "next row", until `fetch` returns FALSE.

```
  $query->execute();
  while ( $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     echo $row['title'];
  }
```

---

There's only one column in the resultset. It seems like we are confused about `fetch` and `fetchAll`.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

---

If we use `fetchAll` to retrieve all of the rows, we get an array back, each element in the array is a row from the resultset.

```
  $query->execute();
  if( $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     foreach($rs as $row) {
        echo $row['title'];
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php says:

> PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set

It only fetches one row each time you call `fetch()`. You either need to call it in a loop until it reaches the end of your result set, or else use `fetchAll()`.

It sounds like you are mixing up the terms "row" and "column" somehow.

Comment: So basically I have to use fetch() only when I expect a single return and fetchall() for multiple returns ?

Comment: I always write my code assuming there will be multiple rows returned. It does no harm if the result has one row, because the loop simply executes just one iteration.